# ios - http request isn't making it to server

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, rest, nsurlconnection

I am trying to send a http request from an ios app on the simulator to a REST service I have running on a local server. I followed some posts on here about how set up a simple request but it doesn't seem to get as far as the REST server. I'm new to this so I'm not where I have gone wrong exactly.

Update: Turns out this was actually contacting the server. The problem appears to be with the MIME type of the request.

Update No.2: I change the NSURLRequest to NSMutableURLRequest, so that I could include this line     `[request setValue:@"text/html" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];`
to change the content type to html. Now I am getting an error though when I try to send the request.
I receive this in the output log

```
:2014-03-26 23:48:07.510 REST[1516:70b] -[NSURLRequest setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a1abe0
2014-03-26 23:48:07.713 REST[1516:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSURLRequest setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a1abe0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0173a5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014bd8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x017d7903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0172a90b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0172a4ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   REST                                0x00001ead -[ViewController fetchTweet] + 237
    6   REST                                0x0000223e -[ViewController go:] + 78
    7   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014cf874 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    8   UIKit                               0x0022d0c2 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    9   UIKit                               0x0022d04e -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    10  UIKit                               0x003250c1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    11  UIKit                               0x00325484 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
    12  UIKit                               0x00324733 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641
    13  UIKit                               0x0026a51d -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 852
    14  UIKit                               0x0026b184 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1232
    15  UIKit                               0x0023ee86 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    16  UIKit                               0x0022918f _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11421
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x016c383f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x016c31cb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x016e029e __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x016dfac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x016df8db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x036df9e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x036df809 GSEventRun + 104
    24  UIKit                               0x0022bd3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    25  REST                                0x00002a2d main + 141
    26  libdyld.dylib                       0x01d78701 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

This is the ViewController.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<NSURLConnectionDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, readwrite, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *button;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *tweetId;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *tweetContent;

@property (nonatomic) NSURLConnection *connection;


- (IBAction)go:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)fetchTweet;


@end
```

This is the ViewController.m file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize button=_button;
@synthesize label=_label;
@synthesize tweetId=_tweetId;
@synthesize tweetContent=_tweetContent;
@synthesize connection=_connection;

- (IBAction)fetchTweet
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1:8080/Jersey/rest/hello"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"Did Receive Response %@", response);
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data
{
    //NSLog(@"Did Receive Data %@", data);
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didFailWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    NSLog(@"Did Fail");
}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"Did Finish");
    // Do something with responseData
}

- (IBAction)go:(id)sender
{
    [self fetchTweet];
    self.label.text = @"Working";
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Do you get any log output / errors / exceptions? Is `fetchTweet` being called? Did you debug (are you sure)?

Comment: Your code should fire, if it does not reach the server, there is a problem with your URL, try with a deferent api. Any how, you should get log response, "Did Receive Response"/"Did Fail".

Comment: This is what I get in the output box after pressing the button. `2014-03-26 22:45:34.722 REST[1278:70b] Did Receive Response <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x8c5ff40> { URL: http://127.0.0.1:8080/Jersey/rest/hello } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Content-Type" = "text/plain";
    Date = "Wed, 26 Mar 2014 22:45:34 GMT";
    Server = "Apache-Coyote/1.1";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
} }
2014-03-26 22:45:34.723 REST[1278:70b] Did Finish`

Comment: My previous answer was wrong. This should indeed fire as other people said. My apologies for the bad answer.

Comment: No worries, sorry about the formatting on that output everyone

Comment: That output shows a response from the server. It even identifies the server (`Apache-Coyote/1.1`). Obviously it has reached the server, so what problem are you trying to fix?

Comment: Ok sorry if it has reached the server, it hasn't gone to the right method in the REST service, is there a simple way to set the MIME type of the request to html, so that it will reach the right method.

Comment: Yes, but maybe you should update your question to describe the problem you're trying to solve, instead of asking one thing and then moving on to other details in the comments.

Comment: Sorry about that I updated the question.

Comment: [request setHTTPMethod:@"Your method like: POST"] check what your sever can get. Did you tried it?

Comment: What happens when you try accessing the server from the browser or `curl` ? what's the output supposed to be ?

Comment: @Mike.R I'm not sure if this will work, the rest service sorts the incoming request by the MIME type they are requesting.

Comment: @MostafaTorbjørnBerg It works from a web browser, it returns a string which is displayed in the browser.

Comment: ok, I see the problem, posting an answer in a few seconds :)

Comment: You are ignoring all data returned in the connection, just throwing it away without even looking at it. How do you know you're not getting the correct response when you're not even looking?

Comment: I see that you reached the sever.... what exactly the problem? The problem in the server? you don't receive what you want?

Comment: @TomHarrington It is meant to trigger an event on the server. I can view the server to see if the event has been triggered. It has not been triggered, so the request hasn't gone to the right place.

Comment: @user3461851 seeing the stack trace you're still trying to modify a `NSURLRequest`, you probably initialised an `NSURLRequest` and assigned it to a `NSMutableURLRequest`, you must init it like this `[[NSMutableURLRequest] alloc] init]`, how do you know that your problem is `content-type` ? I highly doubt that it's your issue..

Comment: @user3461851 As far as I know you should reach one of the GET, POST, PUT and DELETE methods. Can you check which one did you triggered?

Comment: You need to figure out just what it is you're asking. First it was that the request wasn't reaching the server, then it was something about the MIME type, then it was that you weren't getting the string that would be displayed in a browser, now most recently it's that the server is not doing the right thing. Make up your mind and ask a question that can be answered instead of changing the question over and over.

Comment: @MostafaTorbjørnBerg Yes you were correct about initialising the request wrong. I have changed it now and it works but not with the specified content-type. I have three statements on the REST service that call different methods depending on the content type of the request. ex. `@GET
 @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)`,  `@GET
 @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)` and `@GET
 @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)`. Only the TEXT_PLAIN one is firing though, which leads me to believe I have not changed the content type of the request correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're simply ignoring the data that comes in, from the comments I see your server is being reached, if you update your implementation to something like this, it should probably work

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController
{
    NSMutableData *_currentData;
}

@synthesize button=_button;
@synthesize label=_label;
@synthesize tweetId=_tweetId;
@synthesize tweetContent=_tweetContent;
@synthesize connection=_connection;

- (IBAction)fetchTweet
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1:8080/Jersey/rest/hello"];
    self->_currentData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"Did Receive Response %@", response);
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data
{
    //NSLog(@"Did Receive Data %@", data);
   [self->_currentData appendData:data];
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didFailWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    NSLog(@"Did Fail");
    self->_currentdata = Nil;
}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"Did Finish");
    // Do something with responseData
    NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithdata:self->_currentData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]
    NSLog(@"Received data: %@", dataString);
}

- (IBAction)go:(id)sender
{
    [self fetchTweet];
    self.label.text = @"Working";
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer it is helpful. The problem is with the Content-type in the request. When I try to change the request with something like:`[request setValue:@"text/html" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
` so it will trigger the right method on the rest service it tells me that "No visible @interface for 'NSURLRequest' declares the selector 'setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:'" EDIT: Apologies, I fixed that by changing it to NSMutableURLRequest

Comment: @user3461851 Yep as you said that would be `NSMutableURLRequest`, did it help though ? also, does the API call need to be a `POST` or a `GET` method ?, I don't really think that `Content-Type` is your problem here.